# Why Does My Card Move Down The Page When I Use the <a> Tag To Turn It Into A Link

Tags: html, css

Im to html and css and im trying to make a game website for my school but when i try to change div into a on for the card it moves the card down the page as seen in the images bellow,if you guys have any ideas why this is doing this please help im sort of stuck and I want to fiqure this out before I continue with this page.

Before Change
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdTDn.png)

After Change
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0OiW.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     <title>Project-LuLo</title>
     <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
      <style>
         body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.shell{
justify-content:center;
display: flex;
flex-direction:row;
flex-basis: auto;
margin:5px;
}

.card {
  width: 175px;                
  display: flex;              
  flex-direction: column;       
  border: 1px solid #EF9A9A;    
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;  
  text-decoration:none;
}


.card-header {
  color: #D32F2F;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
  background-color: #FFEBEE;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.card-main {
  display: flex;              
  flex-direction: column;     
  justify-content: center;    
  align-items: center;        
  padding: 15px 0;            
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 72px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #D32F2F;
}

.main-description {
  color: #D32F2F;
  font-size: px;
  text-align: center;
}

* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFEBEE;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
   border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: #D32F2F;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #dfd5d7;
  color: #942626;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: #D32F2F;
  color: #FFEBEE;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}

      </style>
   </head>
    <body>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="header">
  <a href="#home" class="logo">Project-LuLo</a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#games">Games</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="shell"> 
<a href = "#test"class="card">
  <div class="card-header">Games</div>
  <div class="card-main">
    <i class="material-icons">videogame_asset</i>
    <div class="main-description">Web Based Games</div>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#test"class="card">
  <div class="card-header">Other</div>
  <div class="card-main">
    <i class="material-icons">question_mark</i>
    <div class="main-description">Cool Random Stuff</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are opening the **<a** but no where are you ending it with **</a>**

Comment: Link can not contain div's inside

Comment: @Justinas this is not correct information

Comment: @Justinas **The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links).** https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-a-element.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a few unclosed `<a>` tags and when you changed one of the tags to an `<a>` it also was removed from inside the `<div>` that contained your `shell` class which was the flex element that was holding the 2 cards beside each-other

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.shell{
justify-content:center;
display: flex;
flex-direction:row;
flex-basis: auto;
margin:5px;
}

.card {
  width: 175px;                
  display: flex;              
  flex-direction: column;       
  border: 1px solid #EF9A9A;    
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;  
  text-decoration:none;
}


.card-header {
  color: #D32F2F;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
  background-color: #FFEBEE;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.card-main {
  display: flex;              
  flex-direction: column;     
  justify-content: center;    
  align-items: center;        
  padding: 15px 0;            
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 72px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #D32F2F;
}

.main-description {
  color: #D32F2F;
  font-size: px;
  text-align: center;
}

* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body { 
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFEBEE;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EF9A9A;
   border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: #D32F2F;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #dfd5d7;
  color: #942626;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: #D32F2F;
  color: #FFEBEE;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="header">
  <a href="#home" class="logo">Project-LuLo</a>
  <div class="header-right">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#games">Games</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="shell"> 
  <a href="#test" class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Games</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">videogame_asset</i>
      <div class="main-description">Web Based Games</div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#test"class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Other</div>
    <div class="card-main">
      <i class="material-icons">question_mark</i>
      <div class="main-description">Cool Random Stuff</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```